# Python Tkinter - Remove dots in .coords widget e.g [720.0] -> [720]

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Im currently having an issue on python3.5-tkinter with this line:
`can1.coords(array[0])`
It return an array of 'double' ***[720.0, 60.0]*** and I'd like it to return an 'integer' ***[720, 60]***.
I already tried the int() and replace() methods but no results.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: How are you displaying the coordinates?

Comment: can1.coords() widget displays coordonates on the form [x, y] but with the unwanted dots (can1 being the prime Canvas)

Comment: You could make a Numpy array from the iterable and change the dtype to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a list of items instead of a single item, use the `map` function:

```
map(int, can1.coords(listmonstre[0]))
```

Comment: print(map(int, can1.coords(listmonstre[0]))) : <map object at 0x03997C30> what does it do ? i don't undertsand.

Comment: @Shampu In python 3, `map` returns `map object`. You need to cast it back to `list`(or set etc.) to print values. `list(map(int, can1.coords(listmonstre[0])))`.